# Drawing the three perpendicular bisectors of the sides of a triangle

Tags: tkz-euclide

[image]

(1). `L`, `M` and `N` must be the mid-points of the sides `AB`, `AC` and `BC` respectively.

(2). `LX`, `MY` and `NZ` must be the perpendiculars.

(3). Note that `LX` and `NZ` must intersect at point `P`, and `MY` must terminate before passing through the point `P`.

```
 \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
 \usepackage{blindtext}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage{tkz-euclide}
 \usetkzobj{all}
 \usepackage{color}

 \begin{document}
 \normalsize{\textbf{Theorem 1.25.} \textit{The three perpendicular bisectors of the sides of a triangle meet in a point which is equally distant from the vertices.}}
 \begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip
(-1,-3) rectangle (13,8);
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
\tkzDefPoint(12,0){B}
\tkzLabelPoints[below](A)
\tkzLabelPoints[below](B)
\tkzDrawSegment(A,B)
\tkzDefPoint(4,7){C}
\tkzLabelPoints[above](C)
\tkzDrawSegment(A,C)
\tkzDrawSegment(B,C)


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: This is really similar to your previous question [Draw three bisectors from the three vertices of a triangle](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228376/draw-three-bisectors-from-the-three-vertices-of-a-triangle), except that you're asking for the bisectors of the sides instead of the angle bisectors. Could you try to get started yourself and ask for more concrete help if you get stuck?

Comment: @Jake I accept my mistake. I should not have posed this question. 
I shall attempt it again.

Comment: @Jake The codes I used were incorrect; `\tkzDefLine[bisector](A,B)`, `\tkzGetPoint{L}` and `\tkzDrawSegment(L,X)`.

Comment: Could you insert your improvements in the code figuring in your question?

Comment: The correct syntax for the bisector of a line segment is `\tkzDefLine[mediator](A,B) \tkzGetPoint{L}`, which stems from the French word "médiatrice" (meaning "bisector of a line segment")

Comment: @fpast I made the improvements in my question. If you could look at it, I would appreciate.

Comment: @Jake Since toy brought that up, now I can continue with it. 
Thank you, Jake!

Comment: @Jake It did not come off well. But at least I knew the code for the mediator. I shall try to find away to work this out. If I knew a method, I certainly would not post this question. I do not have anything to say other than that. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To find the midpoints `L`, `M`, `N`:

```
\tkzDefMidPoint(A,B) \tkzGetPoint{L}
```

To find auxiliary points `X`, `Y`, `Z` on the bisectors of the line segments:

```
\tkzDefLine[orthogonal=through L](A,B) \tkzGetPoint{X}
```

or

```
\tkzDefLine[mediator](A,B) \tkzGetPoint{X}
```

To find intersection `P` of two bisectors `AX` and `BY`:

```
\tkzInterLL(L,X)(M,Y) \tkzGetPoint{P}
```

[image]

```
 \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
 \usepackage{blindtext}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage{tkz-euclide}
 \usetkzobj{all}
 \usepackage{color}

 \begin{document}
 \normalsize{\textbf{Theorem 1.25.} \textit{The three perpendicular bisectors of the sides of a triangle meet in a point which is equally distant from the vertices.}}
 \begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip
(-1,-3) rectangle (13,8);
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
\tkzDefPoint(12,0){B}
\tkzDefPoint(4,7){C}

\tkzDrawSegment(A,B)
\tkzDrawSegment(B,C)
\tkzDrawSegment(C,A)

\tkzDefMidPoint(A,B) \tkzGetPoint{L}
\tkzDefLine[orthogonal=through L](A,B) \tkzGetPoint{X}

\tkzDefMidPoint(B,C) \tkzGetPoint{M}
\tkzDefLine[orthogonal=through M](B,C) \tkzGetPoint{Y}

\tkzDefMidPoint(C,A) \tkzGetPoint{N}

\tkzInterLL(L,X)(M,Y) \tkzGetPoint{P}

\tkzDrawLines(L,X M,Y)
\tkzDrawSegment(N,P)
\tkzMarkRightAngle(A,L,X)
\tkzMarkRightAngle(B,M,Y)
\tkzMarkRightAngle(C,N,P)

\tkzLabelPoints(B,L)
\tkzLabelPoints[below left](A)
\tkzLabelPoints[above](C,M)
\tkzLabelPoints[above left](N)
\tkzLabelPoints[below right](P)

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: If you have not produced an answer, I will never be able to come up with this. The answer is very clear! And the codes were learnt. :)

Answer (score 2):

With MetaPost, as an complement for whom it may interest. With help from the [MetaPost manual](http://www.tug.org/docs/metapost/mpman.pdf) and [André Heck's MetaPost tutorial](https://staff.fnwi.uva.nl/a.j.p.heck/Courses/mptut.pdf) for the macros `mark_right_angle`, `draw_mark` and `tick`.

To find the midpoints:

```
L = .5[A, B]; M = .5[A, C]; N = .5[B, C];
```

The intersection point is found with implicit equations, as often with MetaPost:

```
P = whatever[L, L + (B-A) rotated 90] = whatever[N, N + (C-B) rotated 90];
```

X, Y and Z are built with help of midpoints and numeric parameters `over` and `under` (for their positions relatively to P).

```
X = P + over*unitvector(P-L); 
Y = P - under*unitvector(P-M); 
Z = P + over*unitvector(P-N);
```

The whole code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{luamplib}
    \mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}

vardef mark_right_angle (expr common, endofa, endofb, size) = % right angle mark
    save tn ; tn := turningnumber(common -- endofa -- endofb -- cycle) ;
    draw ((1, 0) -- (1, 1) -- (0, 1))
        zscaled (size*unitvector((1+tn)*endofa + (1-tn)*endofb - 2*common))
        shifted common;
enddef ;

vardef draw_mark(expr p, m, size) = % One mark upon a segment
    save t, dm; pair dm;
    t = arctime m of p;
    dm = size*unitvector(direction t of p rotated 90);
    draw (-.5dm .. .5dm) shifted (point t of p); 
enddef;


vardef tick(expr p, n, size) = % Several marks upon a segment
    save midpnt; midpnt = 0.5*arclength(p);
    for i = -(n-1)/2 upto (n-1)/2:
        draw_mark(p, midpnt+0.6size*i/2, size); 
    endfor;
enddef;

u := 1cm; over := u; under := 0.75u;
pair A, B, C, L, M, N, P, X, Y, Z; path triangle;
A = origin; B = (12u, 0); C = u*(4, 7);
triangle = A -- B -- C -- cycle; 
L = .5[A, B]; M = .5[A, C]; N = .5[B, C];
% Locating the intersection
P = whatever[L, L + (B-A) rotated 90] = whatever[N, N + (C-B) rotated 90];
% Bisectors 
X = P + over*unitvector(P-L); 
Y = P - under*unitvector(P-M); 
Z = P + over*unitvector(P-N);

beginfig(1);
    rsize := 2mm; msize := 3mm;
    draw triangle; draw L -- X; draw M -- Y; draw N -- Z;
    mark_right_angle(L, B, P, rsize); tick(A--L, 2, msize); tick(L--B, 2, msize);
    mark_right_angle(M, C, P, rsize); tick(A--M, 1, msize); tick(C--M, 1, msize); 
    mark_right_angle(N, C, P, rsize); tick(C--N, 3, msize); tick(B--N, 3, msize);
    label.llft("$A$", A); label.bot("$B$", B);
    label.top("$C$", C); label.rt("$P$", P);
    label.llft("$L$", L); label.ulft("$M$", M);
    label.urt("$N$", N); label.top("$X$", X);
    label.bot("$Y$", Y); label.lft("$Z$", Z);
endfig;

\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

To be processed with LuaLaTeX:

[image]

Comment: This is a fantastic set up. `whatever` is a fine code that can be used.